# Do you know of any video lectures in nuclear and particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations

I was hoping the internet would be filled with video lectures since lots of universities have been forced to conduct online teaching.
However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Therefore I was hoping that some of you know of some great video lectures for nuclear and particle physics on undergraduate level (Can be separate courses). I have found some lectures from an Indian university and lectures from a French university. But their English skills don't seem to be the best (No offense). So I was hoping some of you knew of some lectures with a lecturer who speaks English fluently (not necessarily as mother tongue).

Ideally I would like them to cover some/most of the curriculum in "Nuclear and Particle Physics" by Martin and Shaw (see below). But the course doesn't necessarily need to use this book in the course.
Specifically, they should cover Feynman diagrams (The different rules), the different symmetry and conservation laws, the weak and strong and electromagnetic interactions, the different particles of the standard model, etc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e34G0.jpg - Table of Contents - book by Martin and Shaw.

Comment: MIT has online courses free, some with videos, see here  for physics https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/

Comment: Alex Flournoy has a particle physics course that's available on YouTube, though it's more on the theoretical side and misses the second half of your link. Previous years' courses are also available on his YouTube channel. https://inside.mines.edu/~aflourno/Particle/423.shtml

Answer (score 1):

There is a site called [Great Courses](https://www.thegreatcourses.com) that features video lectures on many different subjects including Nuclear Physics and Particle Physics.  These courses usually consist of about 24 videos at 30-40 minutes each. These are not free but if you wait for a sale you can get these videos for about 30-40 dollars.  I think.  You can view the videos online or download them to your machine. Once you buy a course you can view it online forever. I think the nuclear physics course is at an undergraduate level but you can check out the topics covered online..

The Particle Physics course that I saw is for non-physicists and but covers a lot of material. There maybe other particle physics courses.

You could also google something like 'Particle physics tutorials' and this may show you some other sites.